# How do I limit what words can be put into a prompt box to give different prompts per each word?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox, prompt

```
<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = 40
var y = 20
var input
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

    if (person = "luke") {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + x + "! How are you today?";
    }
}
</script>
```

What I have right now in my code is a text box that when you input anything it gives you Hello 40 how are you today? What I want is only if you type fire for it to say that and then after that make different prompts for if you type water or wind ... anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your commented feedback I have modified the code to only accept answers you want to accept, and continue prompting for input until they match what you want. It also fixes a little glitch where they were prompted for their favorite water and earth no matter their input:

For starters, the reason it's outputting "Hello 40" isbecause in your code

```
 `"Hello " + x + "! How are you today?";`
```

You are outputting the variable that has 40 stored in it. You should change x to person, since it contains the name you want to output. As for asking giving other prompts based on output just do:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var element = prompt("Please enter your name", "fire");
var favorite = "";
var testing = 0;
while (testing == 0)
{
if(element == "fire" || element == "water" || element == "earth")
{
    testing = 1;
}
    else
{
    element = prompt("Please enter your favorite element","fire");
    }
}


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "You have chosen " + element + "!";
if (element == "water") {
 favorite = prompt("What body of water is your favorite?")
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
    "And your favorite body of water is" + favorite + "!";
}
 if (element == "earth") {
 favorite = prompt("What formation of earth is your favorite?")
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
    "And your favorite formation of earth is" + favorite + "!";
}
}
</script>
```

Using your code as a template I constructed this. I took out the variables you weren't using to consolidate space. You can easily just copy and paste the "if" statements and place them accordingly to give more options/prompts to the user. If you want to hide one of the text fields make a conditional (if) statement and set the value of the inner html of the element to an empty string (""). Best of luck.

Comment: If you feel this answers your question feel free to "accept" it as the solution. If not, feel free to comment and  I will do my best to further assist you.

Comment: Thank you that seems to work but it still gives me the problem that I can type anything and it will continue, I would like it as one prompt box where if I type water it gives the whats your favorite body of water question, If I type earth right from the get go to get asked something like whats your favorite place on earth and if it's something random like fsdjkfhskjfh to do nothing , sorry I should of been more clear at first greatly appreciate the help so far